# Htaccess, go through files until exists?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp|ico|flv|mpeg|mp4|mp3|swf|exe|WAgame|wsc|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|rar|wav)$ - []
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint3.php
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint2.php
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint.php

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ http://www.example.com [R,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]

<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
```

If the entryPoint3.php exists, load it, otherwise load entryPoint2.php otherwise entryPoint.php. How to achieve this?

Comment: _Aside:_ Why are you redirecting requests for `/robots.txt` to the document root (home page)?

Comment: I dont want robots

Comment: So, why "redirect"? Why not just let it 404? (It's just that redirecting such requests to the home page doesn't really make sense, so I'm wondering what problem you are trying to solve by doing this? If anything, redirecting in this way potentially puts additional unnecessary load on the server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|bmp|ico|flv|mpeg|mp4|mp3|swf|exe|WAgame|wsc|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|rar|wav)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ / [R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# if entryPoint3 exists then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/entryPoint3.php -f
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint3.php [L]

# if entryPoint2 exists then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/entryPoint2.php -f
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint2.php [L]

# if entryPoint exists then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/entryPoint.php -f
RewriteRule ^ entryPoint.php [L]

<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
```

Comment: I solved it like that: DirectoryIndex entryPoint3.php entryPoint2.php entryPoint.php
 what's the difference?

Comment: Indeed `DirectoryIndex` will also work and might be shorter but remember it will try to open `entryPoint` files in every directory not just in site root

Comment: umm, please edit your post, I left the domain name so you did too :(

Answer (score 1):

> I solved it like that: `DirectoryIndex entryPoint3.php entryPoint2.php entryPoint.php` what's the difference?

> ...but remember it will try to open entryPoint files in every directory not just in site root

You can specify root-relative URL-paths as arguments to the `DirectoryIndex` directive, they do not need to be *relative*, as you have here. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex /entryPoint3.php /entryPoint2.php /entryPoint.php
```

This will search for files in the document root only, regardless of which directory is requested.

But also, this is quite different to [@anubhava's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68122140/369434) using mod_rewrite (and similar to what you were attempting in the question). With `DirectoryIndex`, the necessary file will only be served if you are requesting a directory (which includes the document root, ie. `https://example.com/`). eg. `example.com/` and `example.com/directory/` will trigger the relevant `entryPoint` file, but `example.com/something` will not.

However, with the mod_rewrite solution as stated, the relevant `entryPoint` file is served for "any" requested URL (except for the few URL-extension exceptions as stated). eg. `example.com/`, `example.com/something`, `example.com/file.php` and `example.com/directory/` will all trigger the relevant `entryPoint` file.

For the mod_rewrite solution to work the same way as `DirectoryIndex` you will need an additional condition that explicitly checks that the request maps to a directory (including the trailing slash). For example:

```
# When requesting a directing... if entryPoint3 exists (in the root) then use it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/entryPoint3.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?$ entryPoint3.php [L]
:
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* simply checks that the requested URL ends with a slash (or is the document root) - the same behaviour as `DirectoryIndex`. (If you request a directory without a trailing slash then mod_dir appends it with a 301 redirect.)

So the solution you choose really depends on your requirements. However, if `DirectoryIndex` is working for you then I assume you are only requesting filesystem directories, so `DirectoryIndex` would be the way to go.